# jquery replacewith function cant identify id after replace

Tags: jquery

hmmm i am creating a simple system in php and jquery. SO the flow will be. In a table like this
[image]

Once i click the little pencil icon there the value-2 and value-4 will be replace by text.

[image]

i replace the id and image of pencil and make a check meaning once click the value in the textboxes will be saved.

here is my code

```
  <input type="hidden" id="del<?php echo $counter ?>" value="<?php echo $row['sub_code'] ?>" />
                        <td><center><a href = "#" class="a1"><?php echo $row['sub_code']; ?></a></td></center>
                        <td><span class="a2"><?php echo $row['sub_section']; ?></span></td>
                        <td><a href = "#" class="a3"><?php echo $row['sub_desc']; ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['sub_sched']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $row['sub_level']; ?></td></center>
                        <td>
                        <img src="images/edit2.png" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 0px; background-color: white; cursor: pointer;" id="edit" />
                        <img src="images/Delete.png" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 0px; background-color: white; cursor: pointer;" id="delete" />
```

and my jquery code

$("#edit").click(function(){
                                                $(".a1").replaceWith("").replaceWith("");

```
});

$("save").click(function(){
alert("save");
});
```

Once the pencil image become check i click it to have a sample alert but it doesnt. anyone knows why the jquery not reacting in my id. i replace it on the edit function using replacewith but why it doesnt work?

Comment: Please correctly add your code

Comment: have you considered hiding/showing/toggling the pencil and checkmark instead of completely removing one or the other? You might want that pencil back after they click the checkmark...

Comment: buy hiding and showing feels like im cheating in my code :) but if there is no solution i might consider yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$("#edit").on('click', function()
```

and

```
$("#save").on('click', function()
```

Comment: ahm if i search on function in jquery i can see that example? Thank you

Comment: yes will be nice to see... people sometimes downvote just for doing something. To Me and Aelios.

Comment: Not me. Thanks anyway Ill try this on function

Comment: Seems that your function is not well closed: add `();` to your last script line.

Comment: Then write correctly your code: `value="..." name="..." id="..."`

Comment: at the end there is only `})`, it should be `})();`

Comment: Can you please build a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and I will try to solve it before I go off here in office.

Comment: There is no so much in your fiddle, is this what you mean?
[http://jsfiddle.net/Nj3MK/19/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nj3MK/19/)

Comment: No no thats not it. Can u give a simple example using on so if you could? i will make it as my reference on my future projects.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It does not work cause you did not change your previous `edit` id

```
<img src="images/edit2.png" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 0px; background-color: white; cursor: pointer;" id="edit" />
```

Should be

```
<img src="images/edit2.png" style="width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 0px; background-color: white; cursor: pointer;" id="save" />
```

and

```
$("#save").on('click', function() {
alert("save");
});
```

Comment: Downvoter, please comment your downvote ! If no reason remove it

Comment: Sure you're the one who asks the question :)

Answer (score -2):

you can use live function too for this:

```
 $('#save').live('click',function () {
            alert("called");
        });
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. is `.on()` now.